# creating CSV file in local drive with asp.net in azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I have a webapp in which i can create csv file and locate it in my c drive,

It works fine when running locally, but once i deploy the application to Azure

I'm getting  :

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Tuesday_HH19_MI6.csv' is denied.

How can i allow the website to access and create a file in the user's local drive?

I attached the entire log exception from azure if this helps,
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Web App running in Azure can't directly save it to your user's local drive, but it can generate the CSV and then prompt them to download it via the browser.  You can use a few options depending on if you are trying to send that already exists on the filesystem or if you have generated it dynamically and have it as a byte array or stream.

Here are some sample controller methods to give you and idea.  Your controller could be doing a bunch of stuff before the return statement, these examples are simplified.

Existing file on filesystem, use a FileResult:

```
public FileResult DownloadFile()
{
   // create the file etc and save to FS
   return File("/Files/File Result.pdf", "text/csv", "MyFileName.csv");
}
```

If the file is generated in memory and you have it as a byte array:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadContent()
{
   // Create CSV as byte array
   var myfile = MyMethodtoCreateCSV();
   return new FileContentResult(myfile, "text/csv") { 
      FileDownloadName = "MyFileName.csv" 
   };
}
```